# confusing on create nginx file site-available

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Hi I created an instance in ec2 and connected elastic ip to it,

in the instance itself I installed a server that runs with this url http://172.17.0.2:5000/api/v1.0/,

the elastic ip is in this address (for example 54.193.250.150),

I have now installed nginx and I am trying to do the routing from my PC to a server sitting in ec2 ,

so i tried to create site-available file but i this is not working for me i will be very glad to get help with this issue.

server {

```
   listen   80;
```

server_name  54.193.250.150 ;

location api/v1.0

{

```
      proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:5000/api/v1.0;
```

}

}

Comment: Not clear about the question. You have created ec2 and install local nginx server. is that you api endpoint working locally?

Comment: in the ec2 instance i install local nginx server and a server for my app, i want to send requests from another computer to my server through the nginx web server